# Android gradle - Adding dependency for json simple also adds maven directory for library project

Tags: android, gradle

I am adding a gradle dependency for json-simple in my library project. But in jar file i also see a maven directory within META-INF folder. How can i avoid this maven directory from getting added as part of my jar?

Same behavior if i keep the jar in libs and then refer.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1')
}
```

Comment: you keep what jar in libs? `json-simple`?

Comment: It's just part of the jar ... if you don't want it, don't use it. If you add a dependency to json-simple, you'll always get that maven folder